# error using open layers map in drupal 7 on Internet Explorer

Tags: drupal-7, internet-explorer-9, openlayers

the map works fine with firefox and chrome, but in IE9 I get an error.
I am using a view to create the layers.
The problem has to do with the layers, when I disable all of the layers the map shows up fine in IE. But as soon as I mark one of the layers as activated and enabled I get that error : "Error during map rendering: TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'transform': object is null or undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by disabling Adaptive Image Style Module, now the map works in IE9